# String Sequence Analyzer

Tags: c, string, ascii

First need to convert the string into its individual ASCII value and then we have to accomplish following task:

Check if two consecutive ASCII(values of the string) difference is 1 or not. If difference is 1
then they will be coupled together and print them.

ex.
ABCD
individual ASCII value : 65 67 68 69
Difference of two consecutive ASCII value is 1 so coupled together then print them.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

    int main(){

        char str[100];
        int i=0;

        printf("Enter any string: ");
        scanf("%s",str);

        printf("ASCII values of each characters of given string: ");
        while(str[i])
             printf("%d ",str[i++]);



        return 0;
    }
```

This code print the ASCII values but i don't know how to check the difference between two consecutive values and how to couple them.

Comment: Just subtract the values!

Comment: I have no clue what is couple... ABCD should print ABBCCD?

Comment: @nightshade ex. input is ACBE following ASCII values are 65 67 66 69.so difference of two consecutive i.e A and C is not 1, C and B difference is 1 so they will be printed as CB, B and E difference is not 1, so the result of ACBE is CB.So they are coupled.

Comment: I understood the ascii value part, I just don't know what i 'couple together' ABCD has: B - A == 1(print AB?); C - B == 1(print BC?); D - C == 1 (print CD?);

Comment: @nightshade oh got what you mean. see another ex this time you will get it. ABCDH. A-B=1,B-C=1,C-D=1 but D-H is not 1 so the output is ABCD. we will iterate till difference is 1 and print that part.so ABCD is coupled as they were satisfying the condition (difference=1).

Comment: Use `while(str[i+1]-str[i]==1 && str[i+1]!='\0')`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    char str[100]="";
    int i, last;

    printf("Enter any string: ");
    scanf("%s",str+1);//top is dummy

    printf("ASCII values of each characters of given string: ");
    i = 1;
    while(str[i])
         printf("%d ",str[i++]);
    printf("\n");

    last = i;
    for(i=1;i<last;++i){
        if(str[i] == str[i-1] + 1 || str[i] == str[i-1] - 1 || 
           str[i] == str[i+1] + 1 || str[i] == str[i+1] - 1)
            printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why `i=1` and not `i=0` in the for loop?

Comment: @chouaib , It is not necessary to special treatment to the first character in doing so 
The process is simplified for that.

Answer (score 0):

Well to give you a clue and not solve your problem entierly:

As `char` is an integral type in C, do the following:

```
if( 'B' - 'A' == 1){
    printf("OK\n");
}

if( 'C' - 'A' == 2){
    printf("OK\n");
} //etc
```

(On [ideone](http://ideone.com/7Nq0fo))

Just think about what should you change in the loop and I think you'll get the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to go about your problem it after you read string, create a pointer to it, then just advance a pointer through string checking where `*pointer - *(pointer - 1) == 1`. Do this for `pointer values > string[0]` and you can check if your two adjacent characters are coupled. (you will need the absolute value of the difference). A quick hack at your solution would look something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int absdiff (unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    if (a == b) return 0;
    return (a > b) ? a - b : b -a;
}

int main(){

    char str[100];
    char cpl[3];
    cpl[2]='\0'; // null terminate cpl
    //int i=0;

    printf("Enter any string: ");
    scanf("%s",str);

    printf("ASCII values of each characters of given string: \n");
    char *ptr = str;
    while(*ptr) {
         if ((ptr - str) > 0) {
            if (absdiff (*ptr, *(ptr - 1)) == 1) {
                cpl[0] = *(ptr - 1);
                cpl[1] = *ptr;
                printf ("  coupled : %s\n", cpl);
                ptr++;
                continue;
            }
         }
         printf("  %c  =  %u\n",*ptr, *ptr);
         ptr++;
    }
    putchar ('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

And if given the string **'my_dog_is_unable_to_bark.'** would produce the following output:

```
Enter any string: my_dog_is_unable_to_bark.

ASCII values of each characters of given string:
m  =  109
y  =  121
_  =  95
d  =  100
o  =  111
g  =  103
_  =  95
i  =  105
s  =  115
_  =  95
u  =  117
n  =  110
a  =  97
coupled : ab
l  =  108
e  =  101
_  =  95
t  =  116
o  =  111
_  =  95
b  =  98
coupled : ba
r  =  114
k  =  107
.  =  46
```

Of course you can reformat the output in any manner you like, but for illustrative purposes, this gave a good confirmation of the character -> unsigned int values.